# Delay chained promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to do the following but it isn't working. How can I adjust the code to have a delay between `.then` and `.done`?

```
myService.new(a).then(function (temp) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        return myService.get(a, temp);
    }, 60000);
}).done(function (b) {
    console.log(b);
});
```

Comment: What promise library are you using?

Comment: create a new promise in the `then` handler and return it from `then` handler, then in the `timer` resolve the new promise, that will execute the `done` handler

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple delay function that returns a promise and use that in your promise chain:

```
function delay(t, val) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) {
       setTimeout(function() {
           resolve(val);
       }, t);
   });
}

myService.new(a).then(function(temp) {
    return delay(60000, temp);
}).then(function(temp) {
    return myService.get(a, temp);
}).then(function (b) {
    console.log(b);
});
```

---

You could also augment the `Promise` prototype with a `.delay()` method (which some promise libraries like Bluebird already have built-in).  Note, this version of delay passes on the value that it is given to the next link in the chain:

```
Promise.prototype.delay = function(t) {
    return this.then(function(val) {
        return delay(t, val);
    });
}
```

Then, you could just do this:

```
myService.new(a).delay(60000).then(function(temp) {
    return myService.get(a, temp);
}).then(function (b) {
    console.log(b);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.delay()` function set at `Promise.prototype` which returns a new `Promise` having value of original promise.

```js
Promise.prototype.delay = function(t) {
  return this.then(function(data) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve) {
      setTimeout(resolve, t || 0, data);
    })
  })
};

Promise.resolve(123)
.delay(6000)
.then(function(data) {
  console.log(data)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A slightly improved version of jfriend00's approach avoids needing the pass the resolved value like this:

```
function delay(t) {
  return (val) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => resolve(val), t)
    })
  }
}
```

can be used like this:

```
myService.new(a)
  .then(delay(60000))
  .then(function(temp) {
    return myService.get(a, temp);
  }).then(function (b) {
    console.log(b);
  });
```