# Extending the built-in javascript Promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to extend the javascript promise with a new method. This new method in this case is called `foo`, which really does something like this:

```
Promise.foo = function(arg) {
  return this.then( function(result) {
    return result.foo(arg);
  });
};
```

So in short, the foo() function is a shortcut for waiting for a promise to resolve and then calling foo() on the result.

The nature of this function is that it can be chained, just like `then()` can.

```
myPromise.foo(a).foo(b).foo(c);
```

I feel like this should be possible, but I'm just not sure what the right path is.

This is what I've tried:

```
var FooPromise = function() {
   Promise.apply(this, arguments);
}

FooPromise.prototype = Object.create(Promise.prototype);
FooPromise.foo = function(arg) {
  return this.then( function(result) {
    return result.foo(arg);
  });
};
```

To test it out:

```
var test = new FooPromise(function(res, rej) {
   res('bla');
});
```

In firefox this gives me:

```
TypeError: calling a builtin Promise constructor without new is forbidden
```

In Node:

```
TypeError: #<Promise> is not a promise
```

Is this just a limitation of javascript, or is there a way around this?

Comment: perhaps you should use `FooPromise.prototype.foo` - because you'll be working with instances of FooPromise (why not just add it to Promise.prototype.foo in the first place and not use FooPromise at all) -as for your attempt at "inheriting" from Promise - it looks 3 kinds of wrong to begin with

Comment: See [Delay chained promise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38734106/delay-chained-promise/38734306#38734306)

Comment: What is `result.foo`?

Comment: Apparently you can **not** extend `Promise` without using the ES6 `class FooPromise extends Promise` syntax shown by @anete.anetes , because Promise checks [`new.target`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32450516/5217142) to see if it is called as a constructor  - and is required in the ECMA specs to throw an error if not.

Comment: @JaromandaX because I just want to 'subclass' it within the context of my library, I don't want to do a global monkey-patch because I think generally that's a bad practice.

Comment: Fair enough. I don't have a problem with extending built ins myself

Comment: @JaromandaX that might be good enough for your own application, but you wouldn't want your library dependencies to do this. Generally I think it's a good thing for libraries to avoid global modifications.

Comment: @Evert - must be nice not to have to polyfill for Internet Exploder

Comment: @JaromandaX Overriding globals to polyfill internet standards in browsers that don't support them is a great exception to the 'don't override globals' rule. My use-case kinda falls outside of that category though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After more research, I landed on the following solution. There's no need to extend the built-in Promise. All you really need is to make sure your object implements `then` correctly (aka Promise/A+ / thenable).

```
function FooPromise(executor) {

  this.innerPromise = new Promise(executor);

}

FooPromise.prototype = {

 then: function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {

    return new FooPromise(function(res, rej) {

       this.innerPromise.then(res, rej);

    });

  },

  foo: function() {

    return this.then(function(val) {

      return val.foo();

    });

  }

}
```

This works fine in ES5 environments, works perfectly with other promises and even async/await (where available).

I successfully implemented this pattern [this open source library](https://github.com/evert/ketting).

Comment: I like that at 4 years of JS dev Im second guessing if this is yet another poorly documented way of defining a object or just bad syntax. I am 99% sure that this is bad syntax though.

Comment: @gbtimmon: **edit** I see the problem. Disregard last comment

Comment: Dont't forget to also implement catch & finally, which Promise consumers will also expect to exist.

Answer (score 10):

ES6 way:

```
class FooPromise extends Promise {
    constructor(executor) {
        super(executor);
    }
}

var fooPromise = new FooPromise((resolve,reject)=>{
   resolve(null);
});
```

Comment: __TypeError__: The executor of a promise must be a function.

Comment: of course! You need implement basic constructor args) for example: `var fooPromise = new FooPromise((resolve,reject)=>{resolve(1);});`

Comment: Thank you, this is great! I take it this is the only way to do this? Bit worried about using ES6 syntax in browsers still, but perhaps I need to stop worrying =)

Comment: my choise is [tag:typescript]

Comment: @JaromandaX I'd like to avoid transpiling. My goal is build a lightweight library with a low dependency count.

Comment: `I'd like to avoid transpiling` and yet you chose an ES6 answer as the best!? My suggestion for using babel was to better understand how to "properly" extend Promise in ES5

Comment: @JaromandaX do you have an ES5 answer? Afaik Babel actually also has a bug related to this. The other javascript answer is to build your own thenable  or use something like bluebird. I would LOVE an ES5 solution though that doesn't involve writing a promise from scratch. If you got one I'd totally prefer that answer.

Comment: @user4074041 what if I need to resolve or reject my extended promise inside the subclass constructor? In the provided solution resolve / reject functions are not accessible.

Comment: @humkins did you find a solution for that? I'm trying to setup a `then` call inside my constructor, but I get a "too much recursion" error.